# Use two columns as index to calculate a third column

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have one vector

```
>a<-c(4,5,6,7,8)
```

I have one data.frame

```
>df<-data.frame(start=c(1,4),end=c(3,5))
```

I want to create a third column in this df based on the start-end

```
>df

start end
1     1   3   mean(a[1:3])
2     4   5   mean(a[4:5])
```

of course mean(a[df$start:df$end]) does not work.
I have solved this in a long manner by creating a new data.frame, but I am wondering if is there a short way to do.

Comment: For the sake of accuracy, `a` is a [vector](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/vector.html), not a [list](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mapply` to get the `seq` of corresponding elements of 'start' and 'end' column, subset the 'a' based on that index, get the `mean` and assign the output to create the new column ('Mean') in 'df'

```
df$Mean <- mapply(function(x,y) mean(a[seq(x,y)]), df$start, df$end)
```

Comment: can you make the function simpler as just `mean(a[x:y])`?

Comment: @William Yes, that is another option.